# Oracle APEX PL/SQL Procedure Debugging?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert, oracle-apex

I am using a PL/SQL Procedure to Insert one Table that was previously generated into another exisiting table:

```
INSERT INTO REI_LABOUR_COST (DEALER_NUMBER, DEALER_STATUS, BILLING_PARTNER, BSI_GW, YEAR, QUANTITY_FRU, LABOUR_EUR, LABOUR_LOCAL, REQUESTED_RATE)
select c001 as DEALER_NUMBER
     , c002 as DEALER_STATUS
     , c003 as BILLING_PARTNER
     , c004 as BSI_GW
     , c005 as YEAR
     , c006 as QUANTITY_FRU
     , c007 as LABOUR_EUR
     , c008 as LABOUR_LOCAL
     , c009 as REQUESTED_RATE
from apex_collections col
where collection_name = 'COLLECTION' and seq_id != 1
order by seq_id;
```

But it does not work. There is no error message or other sign of the procedure failing, but it does not show any results in the final table.

First question, is there any sign what I did wrong?

Second question, where would I see an error message if the command fails? Can I enable it somewhere?

Comment: Do you get anything from just running the `SELECT` portion?

Comment: Yes, I do. Everything as I planned it to. Would it convert wrong types itself? Like number to varchar or the other way around, given the chars form a valid number?

Comment: Does it work if you remove all of your column aliases? You don't need them for an insert but I don't know if it would cause it to bonk.

Comment: try to remove your ORDER BY clause

Comment: @justiceorjustus I tried both, it doesn't matter. I thought it might help. Online tutorials are very unspecific about this...

Comment: @AndreyKhmelev It doesn't work.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong.  Presumably this insert is performed on a page submit process in an APEX page?  Running the page in debug mode might show a problem somewhere - perhaps the process is not being fired.

Comment: This is not a PL/SQL Procedure as there is no Procedure definition and no begin and end. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/procedure.htm#LNPLS01336  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/overview.htm#g1461293

Comment: @Joe, in context this code would have been put in an Apex process; APEX automatically surrounds this with BEGIN and END.

Comment: @MarkusAppel, check that your application status is "Available with Developer Toolbar", and run the page from the Apex builder environment. You can then click the "Session" button on the developer toolbar, set "View" to "Collections", and click "Set". You can then browse the data in the collection and verify that the data you're expecting to be there is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before making the insert into the database, the apex collection must be updated for each member attribute.

**First Apex process:** On Submit and Before Computation

```
declare
    y pls_integer := 0;
    v_msg varchar2(4000);
begin
    if not apex_collection.collection_exists(p_collection_name=>'COLLECTION') then
        wwv_flow.debug('No Apex collection found!');
    else
        for x in (select * from apex_collections where collection_name = 'COLLECTION' and seq_id != 1 order by seq_id) 
        loop
           y := y+1;
            apex_collection.update_member_attribute (p_collection_name=> 'COLLECTION', p_seq=> x.seq_id,p_attr_number =>1,p_attr_value=>wwv_flow.g_f01(y));     
            apex_collection.update_member_attribute (p_collection_name=> 'COLLECTION', p_seq=> x.seq_id,p_attr_number =>2,p_attr_value=>wwv_flow.g_f02(y)); 
            apex_collection.update_member_attribute (p_collection_name=> 'COLLECTION', p_seq=> x.seq_id,p_attr_number =>3,p_attr_value=>wwv_flow.g_f03(y)); 
            apex_collection.update_member_attribute (p_collection_name=> 'COLLECTION', p_seq=> x.seq_id,p_attr_number =>4,p_attr_value=>wwv_flow.g_f04(y)); 
            apex_collection.update_member_attribute (p_collection_name=> 'COLLECTION', p_seq=> x.seq_id,p_attr_number =>5,p_attr_value=>wwv_flow.g_f05(y)); 
            apex_collection.update_member_attribute (p_collection_name=> 'COLLECTION', p_seq=> x.seq_id,p_attr_number =>6,p_attr_value=>wwv_flow.g_f06(y)); 
            apex_collection.update_member_attribute (p_collection_name=> 'COLLECTION', p_seq=> x.seq_id,p_attr_number =>7,p_attr_value=>wwv_flow.g_f07(y)); 
            apex_collection.update_member_attribute (p_collection_name=> 'COLLECTION', p_seq=> x.seq_id,p_attr_number =>8,p_attr_value=>wwv_flow.g_f08(y)); 
            apex_collection.update_member_attribute (p_collection_name=> 'COLLECTION', p_seq=> x.seq_id,p_attr_number =>9,p_attr_value=>wwv_flow.g_f09(y)); 
        end loop;   
    end if;
exception when others then
    v_msg := ''||sqlerrm;
    wwv_flow.debug('ERR: '||v_msg); 
end;
```

**Second Apex process:** After Submit

```
declare
    v_msg varchar2(4000);
begin
    for x in (select * from apex_collections where collection_name = 'COLLECTION' and seq_id != 1 order by seq_id) 
    loop            
        begin
            INSERT INTO REI_LABOUR_COST (DEALER_NUMBER, DEALER_STATUS, BILLING_PARTNER, BSI_GW, YEAR, QUANTITY_FRU, LABOUR_EUR, LABOUR_LOCAL, REQUESTED_RATE) 
            values(x.c001, x.c002, x.c003, x.c004, x.c005, x.c006, x.c007, x.c008, x.c009);
        exception when others then
            v_msg := ''||sqlerrm;
            wwv_flow.debug('ERR_1: '||v_msg);                   
        end;
    end loop;   
exception when others then
    v_msg := ''||sqlerrm;
    wwv_flow.debug('ERR_2: '||v_msg);   
end;
```

Comment: Could you explain why exactly I need to update the collection? And why is the first process On Submit and the second process After Submit? Also, I don't see On Submit in the drop-down selector, only After Submit, Processing, and some others.

Comment: It is useful when collection data is manually modified by the user. I use Apex 4.2 and I have the On Submit and Before Computation.

Comment: Oh well, I use Apex 5, that might be it. Any idea what I should select instead?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can reference seq_id like that.

Use `APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_MEMBER` to get rid of seq_id 1.

E.g.

```
BEGIN

 APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_MEMBER(
 p_collection_name => 'COLLECTION',
 p_seq => '1'); 

END;
```

Then continue as normal.

Edit - The reason why it will be failing is a wrong data type error. If you check the debugger you should be able to see this.

Comment: Debugger? Where?

Comment: Also, it worked without the INSERT part, even the header was hidden as I wanted.

Comment: The debugger is at the bottom of the screen in the middle of the toolbar.

Comment: Are all columns in your table of type varchar2?

Comment: `seq_id` is a number, there's nothing wrong with referencing it in the where clause like the OP has.

Comment: Fair enough.  I have had the same problem as OP before and filtering out seq_id didn't work for me, hence I used the method I described in my post and it solved the problem.